# Bar chart scale in multi-chart visualisation

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, histograms, charts

This is a rewording of a previous question which probably wasn't very well explained, and so didn't get any responses(!).
I'm trying to create a chart which shows the smooth kernel distribution of three datasets, a box and whisker chart (below) and the histogram of the datasets laid under the kernel distribution. However, because the data is quite close to each other, I've arrange the 'histogram' into a bar chart so that the data can be displayed side by side (rather than stacked or overlapping, which is confusing with this data).

I've managed to get all three charts to show up (with some much appreciated help from others on this site), but the bar chart (histogram) is completely the wrong scale. (See image below)

[image: All three chart types]

When I break them down and display the charts separately though, the scaling is fine:

[image: Curves only]
[image: Histogram only]

Here is the code:

```
S086 = {33.00, 55.74, 46.68, 22.26, 45.05, 41.95, 82.26, 58.79, 30.89,30.89,47.21, 30.16, 17.16, 28.05, 25.63}
T086 = {34.65, 28.52, 9.77, 38.58, 32.03, 22.26, 35.16, 45.26, 21.71,29.26, 34.71, 22.16}
X086 = {23.41, 48.54, 32.97, 28.57, 23.35, 20.70, 35.49, 21.97, 29.81,17.65, 16.73, 15.32, 16.00}
datasets = {{S086}, {T086}, {X086}}
bin = HistogramList[Flatten[datasets]][[1]]
```

and then
(I've removed the box chart to simplify the code)

```
Show[
Plot[140 PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[#], x] & /@ {S086, T086, 
  X086}, {x, 0, 100}, Evaluated -> True, 
PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], 
   RGBColor[0.23, 0.42, 0.63]}, {Thickness[0.01], 
   RGBColor[0.29, 0.53, 0.80]}, {Thickness[0.01], 
   RGBColor[0.62, 0.73, 0.88]}}, Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> Automatic], 
BarChart[Transpose@(BinCounts[#, {bin}] & /@ {S086, T086, X086}), 
Axes -> False, 
ChartStyle -> {Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.23, 0.42, 0.63]], 
  Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.29, 0.53, 0.80]], 
  Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.62, 0.73, 0.88]]}, 
PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> None]]
```

Comment: The problem is actually just that the 'histogram' and the smooth distributions don't line up, no? In which case presenting all the extra code for the box whisker and grid plot is only muddying the waters.

Comment: The problem arises because `BarChart` uses a x-value of 1 for each bar (or bar position). So for your 9 groups of 3 bars your bar plot only extends up to around x=27, which is what you see when you use `Show` with the `Plot` which goes up to 100.

Comment: I've edited the original posting to just show the relevant portions as you recommended. Is there a solution you can think of to the problem? I've tried playing around with the plot range, but to no avail... I'm relatively new to Mathematica so nearly everything is trial and error for me really.

Answer (score 11):

`Histogram` does not support a grouped `ChartLayout`. Hence the workaround using `BarChart`:

> I've arranged the 'histogram' into a bar chart so that the data can be displayed side by side.

An alternative to using `BarChart` with `"Grouped"` layout is to 
use a custom `ChartElementFunction` to produce the desired `Histogram` layout:

```
ClearAll[groupedHistogram]
groupedHistogram[cef_: "Rectangle", opts : OptionsPattern[]][n_: 1, 
   s_: {0, 0}][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, y_, {i_Integer}] := 
 ChartElementDataFunction[cef][ With[{x0 = xmin + s[[1]] (xmax - xmin)/n, 
    x1 = xmax -  s[[1]] (xmax - xmin)/n}, 
     {x0 + (x1 - x0)/n {s[[2]] + i - 1, i - s[[2]]}, {ymin, ymax}}], y]
```

**Examples:**

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1/2], 500];
data3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1], 500];
dataall = {data1, data2, data3};
Row[{Histogram[dataall, ImageSize -> 300], 
  Histogram[Thread[dataall -> Range[3]], 
    ChartElementFunction -> groupedHistogram[][3, {.3, .2}], ImageSize -> 300]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
opdata = Thread[{S086, T086, X086} -> Range[3]];
styles = {ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True};
```

Combine with `SmoothHistogram` using `Epilog`:

```
sh = SmoothHistogram[{S086, T086, X086}, 
   PlotStyle -> (Directive[Thick, #] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue})];

Histogram[opdata, ##& @@ styles, ChartElementFunction -> groupedHistogram[][3, {.1, 0}], 
 Epilog -> MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ScalingTransform[140, {0, 1}]] &,
    sh, {1}][[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Further Examples:**

```
Histogram[opdata, ## & @@ styles, ChartElementFunction -> groupedHistogram[][3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Control spacings between and within groups:

```
Row[Histogram[opdata, ## & @@ styles, PlotLabel -> "bar spacings: " <> ToString@#,
    ChartElementFunction -> groupedHistogram[][3, #]] & /@ {{.2, .0}, {.1, .1}}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Combine with built-in `ChartElementDataFunction`s for `Histogram`:

```
Row[Histogram[opdata, ##& @@ styles, PlotLabel -> "chart element function: " <> #, 
    ChartElementFunction -> groupedHistogram[#][Length@dd, {.1, .1}]] & /@
     {"ArrowRectangle", "FadingRectangle"}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use alternative bin specifications:

```
Row[Histogram[opdata, #, ##& @@ styles, PlotLabel -> "bins: " <> ToString@#, 
    ChartElementFunction -> groupedHistogram[][Length@dd, {.1, .1}]] & /@ 
      {Automatic, {Range[0, 100, 20]}}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use alternative height specs:

```
Row[Histogram[opdata, Automatic, #, ##& @@ styles, PlotLabel -> "height :" <> #, 
    ChartElementFunction -> groupedHistogram[][3, {.1, .1}]] & /@ 
     {"Probability", "SurvivalCount"}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

Rather than `Show`, you can use [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) + [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) with [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html):

```
Plot[
 140 PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[#], x] & /@ {S086, T086, X086}, {x, 0, 100}, 
 Evaluated -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[0.23, 0.42, 0.63]},
   {Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[0.29, 0.53, 0.80]}, 
   {Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[0.62, 0.73, 0.88]}},
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Prolog -> Inset[
   BarChart[
    Transpose[BinCounts[#, {0, 100, 10}] & /@ {S086, T086, X086}],
    Axes -> False,
    BarSpacing -> {0, 1},
    ChartStyle -> {
      Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.23, 0.42, 0.63]], 
      Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.29, 0.53, 0.80]],
      Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.62, 0.73, 0.88]]}],
   Scaled@{0, 0},
   Scaled@{0, 0},
   Scaled@1]
]
```

> [image: plot1]

This is a little crowded to my eye, so if use permits it, you could stack the distributions:

```
Plot[
 Accumulate[140 PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[#], x] & /@ {S086, T086, X086}], {x, 0, 100},
 Evaluated -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[0.23, 0.42, 0.63]}, 
   {Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[0.29, 0.53, 0.80]}, 
   {Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[0.62, 0.73, 0.88]}},
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Prolog -> Inset[
   Histogram[
    {S086, T086, X086}, {0, 100, 10},
    Axes -> False, 
    ChartStyle -> {
      Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.23, 0.42, 0.63]], 
      Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.29, 0.53, 0.80]],
      Opacity[0.75, RGBColor[0.62, 0.73, 0.88]]},
    ChartLayout -> "Stacked"],
   Scaled@{0, 0},
   Scaled@{0, 0},
   Scaled@1]
]
```

> [image: plot2]