# Histogram of two data sets

Tags: histograms, charts

I want to plot a histogram of two data sets in the following way:

[image]

I've written this code, and following are my results:

[image]

Can you help me out? What should I do?

Comment: Please stop posting images of your code instead include a copyable working example. See [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As stated in linked page you should show some effort, is `Histogram[{a,b}]` all you've tried? Have you seen its documentation? And 'see also' section? p.s. See `BarChart/BinCounts` etc too.

Comment: Yes, I did try BarChart, but it just displays one value at one place, and not that how many times those numbers appeared. BinCounts also didn't help.

Comment: You have to pore through the examples. Try something like `bins = Range[0, 3]/2. - 0.25; BarChart[Transpose[BinCounts[#, {bins}] & /@ {data1, data2}], ChartLabels -> {Range[0, 2]/2, None}, ImageSize -> 600]`.

Comment: Thanks Michael..

Comment: You should look at `HistogramList` as a source of the data you need to transform your data into a bar chart.

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate: [Multiple histograms grouped in a chart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51752/125)

Comment: .. and  related: [Bar chart scale in multi-chart visualisation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113833/125)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your choice of example datasets (which always produces mirror image histograms), so I am going to  contrive my own.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data1 = RandomChoice[{0, 1/2, 1}, 100]
SeedRandom[24]; data2 = RandomChoice[{0, 1/2, 1}, 100]
```

Now, I will use `HistogramList` list to get the data transformed into something useful for making a bar chart.

```
{lblData, barHeight1} = HistogramList[data1, 3];
{notUsed, barHeight2} = HistogramList[data2, 3];
labels = Row[{#1, " – ", #2}] & @@@ Partition[lblData, 2, 1];
```

With the computed data, the bar chart can be made with

```
BarChart[Transpose[{barHeight1, barHeight2}], ChartLabels -> {labels, None}]
```

[image: chart]